# Create Website for a Github Project

Tags: html, github, web, jekyll, github-pages

I've built a software project and hosted it on Github. Now, I'd like to create an accompanying website (with some features like 'About Me', 'Documentation', 'Further Information', etc.). I also have some JavaScript content that should be located there. That's why I'm looking for an easy way to create and maintain a nice website (by the way, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04). I looked at Github pages, the themes are pretty beautiful there, but it just creates one page and no subpages. Nevertheless, I think Github would be a good host for my website in any case. But before diving deeper into plain HTML and adding further pages, I'd like to have some advice:

- What about Jekyll? Is it only convenient for blog posts? In my case I would just like to create a static website with several pages. Do you think that it'd be recommendable for me?
- What are the alternatives? I mean, is there any good recent tool that facilitates website development, produces beautiful, lean pages without previous knowledge?

I know that I can create pages in HTML and CSS with standard editors and I've done that before (years ago). However, I have absolutely no idea about current developments. That's why I'm looking for a modern way for creating accompanying websites for software projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jekyll, you can create not only blog posts, but static sites with several pages as well.

One example hosted on GitHub Pages is the [Jekyll site](http://jekyllrb.com/) itself.
The source code is [in the `gh-pages` branch of the Jekyll repository](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/tree/gh-pages).

Jekyll is easy to get started with - check the [docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/).
You might also want to take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for some [basic HTML templates](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The Bootstrap templates look very promising. In fact, I already started using Jekyll, but then I was wondering if it is the 'state of the art' for software project websites and if there are any alternatives (e.g. anything like ready-made websites with building blocks).